# How to break AES CBC PADDING with chosen ciphertext attack

Tags: aes, chosen-plaintext-attack, chosen-ciphertext-attack

I'm doing a penetration testing for a web application that uses AES CBC PADDING encryption for the parameter ?email=ciphertext then it's printing the plaintext email on html body.

I would like to know if is there any possibility to :

- Crack the IV or the KEY using chosen plaintext attack?
- Can i encrypt a given plaintext?

Comment: Huh? I'm not sure if I understand your 2nd point: `Can i encrypt a given plaintext?` AES has been build to encrypt plaintext and decrypt the resulting ciphertext. If you wouldn't be able to encrypt a given plaintest with  AES CBC PADDING - what else would you be using it for? Can you please clarify that?

Comment: @e-sushi I mean is there any way to generate a ciphertext for this string "' or '1'='1"  using AES CBC padding oracle attack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can deduce the IV by passing in a chosen ciphertext. This ciphertext should be of the form `C = C0||C0`, where `C0` is the first ciphertext block, and `||` is the concatenation operator. In other words, send the same block twice!

This will get you two blocks of plaintext, `P0||P1`. We have that

```
Decrypt(key, C0) ^ IV = P0
Decrypt(key, C0) ^ C0 = P1
```

Therefore,

```
P1 ^ C0 = Decrypt(key, C0)
P0 ^ P1 ^ C0 = IV
```